# "Credentials from google.auth specified, but httplib2 needs to be installed" - Already installed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am trying to set up OAuth2 login with Python/App Engine and had it working briefly until it suddenly stopped working. Log is showing the following:

```
'Credentials from google.auth specified, but '
ValueError: Credentials from google.auth specified, but google-api-python-client is unable to use these credentials unless google-auth-httplib2 is installed. Please install google-auth-httplib2.
```

I have httplib2 in my project's `lib` folder. I also tried installing with `pip install google-auth-httplib2` but the error is still there.

Here is my login code:

```
import logging
import jinja2
import os
import webapp2

import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.contrib.appengine import OAuth2Decorator


from google.appengine.api import users


decorator = OAuth2Decorator(
    client_id='REMOVED',
    client_secret='REMOVED',
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login')


service = build('plus', 'v1')


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    @decorator.oauth_aware
    def get(self):

        if decorator.has_credentials():
            response = service.people().get(userId="me").execute(http=decorator.http())
            # Write the profile data
            self.response.write(unicode(response))
        else:
            url = decorator.authorize_url()
            self.response.write('You must login : <a href="'+url+'">Go</a>')


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [
     ('/', MainHandler),

     (decorator.callback_path, decorator.callback_handler())

    ],
    debug=True) #remove debug=true before final
```

Comment: I think  just having httplib2 is not enough, have a look here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-auth-httplib2

Comment: Try importing it as well? `import google_auth_httplib2`

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your case by mis configuring the requirements.txt [1]. I started the tests from this sample [2] about big query and modified to your scope. Here the ClientId and ClientSecret are in a json file. You can get the contents from that json from [3]. You need to create an OAuth Credential and copy the json content to your client_secret.json.

In the sample you can see a requirements.txt that lists the dependencies for the appengine application. Run the next command inside the folder where the sample lives to install all the dependencies on a local lib folder in the same path:
    pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib/

My requirements.txt looks like:

```
google-api-python-client==1.6.4
google-auth==1.2.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.2
```

Then you can browse the dependencies for your project on that lib/ folder. In the root of the program, where the main.py habits, there is a file named appengine_config.py  that loads the lib folder into your GAE Application and make you able to import those libraries on your Python program. The appengine_config.py looks like:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
# Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

Also, there is the client_secrets.json, where you need to place the contents about your clientId and your clientSecret.

Deploy your app with the same imports as the bigquery sample and you should get it to work.

```
gcloud app deploy
```

I’m sharing the modified code here. Hope it helps:

```
import json
import os

import googleapiclient.discovery
from oauth2client.contrib.appengine import 
OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets
import webapp2


# The project id whose datasets you'd like to list
PROJECTID = 'Your-project-id'

# Create the method decorator for oauth.
decorator = OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'client_secrets.json'),scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')
#decorator = OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'client_secrets.json'),scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login')

# Create the bigquery api client
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2')


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    # oauth_required ensures that the user goes through the OAuth2
    # authorization flow before reaching this handler.
    @decorator.oauth_required
    def get(self):
        # This is an httplib2.Http instance that is signed with the user's
        # credentials. This allows you to access the BigQuery API on behalf
        # of the user.

        http = decorator.http()
        response = service.datasets().list(projectId=PROJECTID).execute(http)

        self.response.out.write('<h3>Datasets.list raw response:</h3>')
        self.response.out.write('<pre>%s</pre>' % json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=4,separators=(',', ': ')))


class MainAware(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    # credentials. This allows you to access the BigQuery API on behalf
    # oauth_required ensures that the user goes through the OAuth2
    # authorization flow before reaching this handler.
    @decorator.oauth_aware
    def get(self):
        # This is an httplib2.Http instance that is signed with the user's
        # credentials. This allows you to access the BigQuery API on behalf
        # of the user.
        if decorator.has_credentials():
            http = decorator.http()
            response = service.datasets().list(projectId=PROJECTID).execute(http)
            self.response.out.write('<h3>Datasets.list raw response:</h3>')
            self.response.out.write('<pre>%s</pre>' % json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=4,separators=(',', ': ')))

        else:
            url = decorator.authorize_url()
            # Write a page explaining why authorization is needed,
            # and provide the user with a link to the url to proceed.
            # When the user authorizes, they get redirected back to this path,
            # and has_credentials() returns True.
            self.response.out.write(url)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/aware', MainAware),
    # Create the endpoint to receive oauth flow callbacks
    (decorator.callback_path, decorator.callback_handler())
], debug=True)
# [END all]
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env#setting_up_libraries_to_enable_development

[2] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/bigquery

[3] https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=your-project-id